# Writing a binary file

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy, scikit-image

The following code writes a binary file in matlab:

```
data = readtif('infile.tif')
fid = fopen('outfile.bin', 'w');
fwrite(fid, data, 'float');
fclose(fid);
```

How can I do it using python? I have a tiff file (data type is float).

Comment: Use skimage.imread to read in the file, and then write the bytes out with standard Python functionality, or with numpy's save or with skimage.imsave.

Comment: @StefanvanderWalt So, `data = skimage.imread('infile.tif'); skimage.imsave('outfile.bin', data)` is sufficient?

Comment: It depends on the output format you want.  Imsave will write to formats like JPG or TIFF.  Do you just want a dump of the bytes?

Comment: @StefanvanderWalt Since the output is `.bin` I think yes just dumping of bytes.

Comment: b = io.imread('/tmp/image.png');
with open('/tmp/file.bin', 'wb') as f:
     f.write(b)